# Is it possible to enable or disable conversation view of Gmail through Gmail API?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I want to programmatically enable/disable Gmail Thread Conversation view On/Off. Can it be achieved using Gmail Rest API. In the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference), I can't find any method for performing this operation.

[Conversation view option in Gmail Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81woR.png)

Comment: This is an interface modification, you can't modify the Gmail interface from the API.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this programmatically, other than opening it in browser and clicking on it ?